# Sourceforge how to extract issues with issue's URL from json files?

Tags: json, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, sourceforge

I have extracted some JSON files for sourceforge projects.

I'm interested with the issue-tracking information - here is an example of the extracted issue tracker information for a particular project.

```
"trackers":[
{"name":"Bugs","location":"http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=100009&atid=626038"},    {"name":"Support Requests","location":"http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=100009&atid=626039"},    {"name":"Feature Requests","location":"http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=100009&atid=626041"}    ]
```

However when I follow the URL to the bug location it doesn't open the issues, it opens the project page.

Is there away to link directly to an issue given the issue's URL?

Comment: Is it possible that this project doesn't have an issue tracker, or isn't publicly available? I can't see to find a link to it on the project page.

Comment: correct, but sometimes this kind of projects provide the links of issue trackers of their own websites !! so instead of tracking the project's issues on sourceforge you have to go to the original website and start from there